# AS3 ENTER_FRAME event still firing when frame changed

Tags: actionscript-3

Why won't this ENTER_FRAME event stop firing when I call view_stats_exit before going to view_start?

```
public function view_start (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop("start");
}
public function view_stats(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Event
    StatsUI.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,stats_scroll);
}
public function view_stats_exit (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    StatsUI.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,stats_scroll);
    view_start(null);
}
```

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
 at Snapshot/stats_scroll()

Comment: works if I change the StatsUI display object to just stage. Can't I attach an ENTER_FRAME event listener to a display object (movie clip)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event listener to  a MovieClip , but you shouldn't do it as a static function , like in your example. The following should work...

```
  private var ui:StatsUI = new StatsUI();

  public function view_stats(e:MouseEvent):void
  {
     // Event
     ui.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,stats_scroll);
  }

  public function view_stats_exit (e:MouseEvent):void
  {
     ui.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,stats_scroll);
     view_start(null);
  }
```